# Webservice is not working in android-ice cream sandwich(api 15)

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I'm trying to invoke a public web service via KSOAP(2.5.8). But it is not able to get data from service in ice-cream sandwich versions. It work's fine in lower versions like 2.2 and 2.3.
Here's my code.

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.util.Log;

public class WebService {

private final String NAMESPACE ="http://aaaaaa.org/";   
private final String URL ="http://5xxxxxxxxxxx.asmx?WSDL";






    public boolean checkUser(String _EmailID, String _Password) {


        boolean result = false; 

        final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://aaaaaaaa/Login";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";

              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo propertyInfoEmail = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfoEmail.setName("_EmailID");
        propertyInfoEmail.setValue(_EmailID);
        propertyInfoEmail.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(propertyInfoEmail);

        PropertyInfo propertyInfoPassword = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfoPassword.setName("_Password");
        propertyInfoPassword.setValue(_Password);
        propertyInfoPassword.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(propertyInfoPassword);

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true; // put this only if the web service is .NET one
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("myApp", response.toString());
            if(response.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Every time it returns false result in ice-cream sandwich . It doesn't show anything in error log. What should i change here. plz help me.

Comment: accept answer of your previously asked questions and any error while connecting to web service

Comment: ok.
no errors while connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ICS will not let you to do some networking stuff on activity. That means that you have to place your call to web service in a background task (AsyncTask). In this link you can see what to do: [here](http://android4ics.blogspot.com/2011/12/consuming-net-web-service-in-android-40.html)